# Energy released from destruction of an object

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, potential-energy, mass-energy

**In the movie “Star Wars: A New Hope”, Luke Skywalker blows up the „Death Star‟. Assume
that the „Death Star‟ is a perfectly spherical spaceship with uniform mass distribution. The mass
of „Death Star‟ M= 1021 kg and the radius R= 667 km. Estimate the amount of energy that was
released when the Death Star was destroyed.**

**Assume that initially all the energy was stored as the gravitational potential energy of the „Death
Star‟ and that after the explosion, the remaining parts of the spaceship are infinitesimally small
and infinitely far from each other.**

I am trying to solve this problem. I was thinking to calculate the potential energy. That should be equal to the energy released. As mentioned in the question, it was stored as gravitaional potential energy.

But the problem is, we know

$$ P.E. = mgh $$

As the height is not mentioned here, how can I calculate it? Besides, **g** should not affect this as well(the thing was a spaceship)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The energy required by the question is the [gravitational self-binding energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_binding_energy). When two elements of masses exist near each other, there is a certain energy associated with the system. This is the same energy of a ball at some height from the earth's surface ($mgh$). But, this formula is limited to the Earth and other objects.

What you need to use for the question is, $U = \frac{3GM^2}{5R}$

Comment: Thank you very much! I guessed there must be some other topics and equations for this. But couldn't find something related. Thanks a lot!